# Jenkins deploy to a specific folder

Tags: jenkins, deployment

How can I deploy to a specific local folder in Jenkins?

Is there a plugin or script that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the option "Restrict where this project can be run"
on "Label Expression" put the Jenkins slave that you are working on.

If you need to set an specific path inside your jenkins slave, go to "Advanced",  search for "Use custom workspace" and set the path to your folder